How do I remove a history of used commands when I press the "up" key?
Basically, I used a couple commands, and whenever I use the ↑ key, I can see those previously used commands, so the question is:
How do I remove them, so that once I press ↑, there will be no history of used commands?

Go to .minecraft (inside of AppData folder) and find the command_history.txt file.

Pro tip: If you add a bunch of empty lines at the beginning of that file, it will stay that long, so you will have a longer command history.

See Where is my Minecraft folder on Windows? if you're having trouble finding the directory.
